# In Swift, how can I get the UNIX Epoc timestamp, in milliseconds?

Tags: ios, swift

```
    UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

This only gets the timestamp in seconds, but not milliseconds.

Comment: Multiply by 1000. To covert any X to milliX you simply multiply by 1000.

Comment: You mean you explicitly cast all decimals away and then complain they are not there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiply by 1000.

```
UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0)
```

Comment: I'd like it to be more accurate.

Comment: More accurate than what? `timeIntervalSince1970` is already giving you results in milliseconds. That's why it is a double.

Comment: @rmaddy I believe you mean seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: @DMan No, I mean milliseconds. The integral part is in seconds but the resolution of the value is in milliseconds (or more).

Comment: @rmaddy Ah I see what you mean.